# Creating XML comments as intellisense in Visual Studio

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I've looked around and have not found a definitive answer. Can someone answer this question?

When creating a DLL, I want to have my XML comments show up as intellisense when another programmer uses my DLL. How do I do get the XML comments I've added to show up?

Do I have to give the other programmer the DLL **and** the XML comments file, for it to work in their Visual Studio as intellisense? What about if I want to add the DLL to the GAC on their computer. Can they still see the intellisense?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have comments in IntelliSense for function in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529677/how-to-have-comments-in-intellisense-for-function-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I found - you would need to add the XML file - VS can find it if they're in the same location.