# How do i throw an exception explicitly in c#?

Tags: c#, exception

In Java i can explicitly specify that a method throws an exception like:

```
public void read() throws IOException{}
```

What is the c# equivalent of this?

What are the best practices for throwing custom exceptions?

I have made them serializable and provided a  streaming context also .

Comment: No, that's not how you throw an exception in Java. That's how you declare a method that throws an exception.

Comment: That an *exception specification*.  It is widely considered to be a mistake, C# doesn't have it and it is deprecated in C++.

Comment: my bad what i meant was how do i declare a method that throws an exception in C#..i apologise...

Comment: oki.so exception specification is a bad idea.. now for e.g. so how do i ask the caller to handle an exception that was thrown by his bad parameters ?

Comment: throw new Exception() -> throws an exception 2 caller.

throw new ArgumentException() ->a standard in framework. Or you can customize this

Comment: @ashutoshraina why exactly is it a bad idea to specify which Exceptions may be thrown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're referring to is the actual *documentation* of code that throws exceptions.

Read this thread that discusses this question: [How to document thrown exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461306/how-to-document-thrown-exceptions-in-c-net)

Comment: @ashutosh What do you want then? in C# you can only document what exceptions a method throws. You can't make them a part of the signature of the method. Ie there's no way of having the compiler tell the caller of a method that he didn't handle specific exceptions. He can read the documentatio if such exist or figure it out at run time

Comment: @Rune FS ,@liortal  yes ,i had a closer look at the exception specification for C#,it seems i just have to specify in the documentation what exceptions my method might throw and have the caller handle it . thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The topic in MSDN called [Exceptions and Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx) covers [Creating and Throwing Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx) in detail.

However, exception specifications are not part of the C# language like they are in Java.  You must rely on documentation to tell the user of your API what exceptions may be thrown.  You cannot force a user to handle an exception, or document it in code.